# What are the differences between the interface orientation delegate methods

Tags: iphone

anyone can tell differences among 
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation,
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation,
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation,

Answer (score 8):

iOS originally did all rotations in a two-step process.  In iOS 3.0, a new/better one-step animation process was introduced.  The methods you mention are called at different stages in rotation.  Specifically,

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is called whenever the view is going to rotate (using any rotation method), before any rotation is started.  This method will be called on ANY version of iOS, ANY time a rotation is performed (on an actively-shown view)

`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is called during a one-step rotation operation, just before the animation is drawn.  This will only be called on iOS 3.0+.

`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` is called at the end of a rotation operation (using any rotation method), after the rotation is complete.  This method will be called on ANY version of iOS, ANY time a rotation is performed (on an actively-shown view).

In practice, on any modern (3.0+) iOS, all three methods are sent to the view controller of the actively-shown view.  The methods are called in the order listed:

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` first
`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` second,
`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` last

Note: iOS 5 deprecates the other rotation-notification methods (dealing with the two-step animation process), so these three are the only ones that should be used in new projects.

Answer (score 3):

From the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ```
> willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
> ```
>
> Sent to the view controller just
>   before the user interface begins
>   rotating.

---

> ```
> willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
> ```
>
> Sent to the view controller before
>   performing a one-step user interface
>   rotation.

---

> ```
> didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
> ```
>
> Sent to the view controller after the
>   user interface rotates.

Comment: Previously, the app would get a notification in the middle of the rotation, splitting the rotation into two phases, but now you can code it for just one phase.

Answer (score 1):

The most significant difference I think is when method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is called the `self.view.bounds` doesn't change but when method `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is called `self.view.bounds` has changed